# Array of Generic Type not showing property

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm missing something. This is too simple to be giving me problems.

**Entity.ts**

```
    export class Entity {
    id: number;
}
```

**search-bar.ts**

```
import { Entity } from './../resources/entity';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export abstract class SearchServiceBase<T extends Entity> {
    public GetAll(): Observable<T[]> {
        const values: T[] = [
            { id : 1 } <-- ERROR Can't assign to type T
        ];

        return of(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know that `{id: 1}` is a valid value of type `T`.  The constraint `T extends Entity` means `T` can be any subtype of `Entity` chosen by the code that calls the constructor of `SearchServiceBase`.  Inside the implementation of `GetAll()` you don't know exactly what `T` will be.

For example, changing your code to the following [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (I removed dependencies on angular since that's presumably not your issue):

```
class Entity {
  id: number = 0;
}

class SearchServiceBase<T extends Entity> {
  public GetAll() {
    const values: T[] = [
      { id: 1 } //<-- ERROR Can't assign to type T
    ];
  }
}
```

Consider what happens with the following code:

```
class Hmm extends Entity {
  readonly hmm = "hmmmmmm";
}

const hmmSearch = new SearchServiceBase<Hmm>();
hmmSearch.GetAll(); //
```

What happens when you run `hmmSearch.GetAll()`?  Well, it's the equivalent of:

```
class HmmSearchServiceBase {
  public GetAll() {
    const values: Hmm[] = [
      { id: 1 } //<-- ERROR Property 'hmm' is missing
    ];
  }
}
```

And as you can see, `{id: 1}` is not a valid `Hmm`.  So the compiler is right to issue the error in your original code.

Now, I'm not sure how to fix this code to make it work, since I'm not familiar enough with angular or rxjs to figure out what you're trying to do.  It is often not possible to assign a value of a concrete type to a variable of a generic type, since guaranteeing that the concrete type is assignable to every possible instantiation of the generic type is difficult.  If you want a value of generic type `T`, you probably have to have one passed in to the function or class constructor somewhere.

Oh well, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECiB2AXAlogntA3gKGtZAJgFzTwCuAtgEYCmATtALzQAMA3NgL7baiQwBlGmDrAAFkLoA3ZMBoAhSDQA8AFWg0AHohrwCMBCnQA+LLmgAHMlRCzoAcRqIAgiBAAKAJRm8eYAHt4CERoKTAQMhoIElUAbQBdJmhY818sfGJoAEZoTmgAenzlAFpiuAAlcoB5cugAYTB4AHIQ-mQAc3hoRH9utAsaaFVU6HiOPG5uXnAoaAAJCgoNbV19OCRUDBw8OmECQJAMMUWkgCJjxcvTjimAoJCLoRFxJPgaAHdoJ9EJehk5RQQFQLCjGLwcR7CH4AOkcLjc4IK+WggD4NwAouzxChoAI5kZBhEC6EI9ab8eaLb7iST-BRKHyWay2YAOJyuDzeba+O7BULhSLRckUBJJFJpPCYDIkHJ5QolMqwSo1aAABTo-gGdHQ0CaFya+BgFGQUGQ8HaIzG5km2CAA)

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your comment. Surely I'm wrong but, if class Hmm extends Entity, shouldn't Hmm inherit the 'id' property?

Comment: Yes, it does; the problem with `Hmm` isn't the `id` property.  It has an additional `hmm` property that `Entity` isn't known to have. And since the value `{id: 1}` is missing the `hmm` property, it is not a valid `Hmm`. `T` is possibly *narrower* than `Entity` (that's what `T extends Entity` means) so while you can safely assign a `T` value to an `Entity` variable, you cannot safely assign an `Entity` value to a `T` variable. `Hmm` is just one possible case which shows how this can fail. Another is `interface IdIsTwo {id: 2}` in which the `id` property must be `2`, and `{id: 1}` doesn't fit.

Comment: Right, I got it. Maybe it'll be more easy if I try to explain what I'm trying to do: I want a generic service, wich will always return an array of object wich always have an 'id' property.

Comment: When you say you want it to be "generic", I'm not sure what you mean.  But if all you know about the output is that it will be an `{id: number}` and you are assigning a concrete value like `{id: 1}` to it, then you need to return/assign-to the concrete type `Entity` and not the generic type `T`.

Comment: I have two entities Customers and Companies. I want to use the same service to get a list of both (In the future could be another entity). Both entites only have in common the 'id' property so, if in the future I wanted to create another method that could filter by id I had the job done thank to extends Entity class. Maybe my mistake is trying to return {id: 1} specifically for testing

Comment: Yes, that's why the compiler is unhappy.  If you just want to do it for testing you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to claim that `{id: 1}` is a `T` like `{id: 1} as T` (or perhaps `{id: 1} as any as T` depending on how resistant the compiler is to the first assertion)... of course you'd want to remember to go back and fix it once you actually have objects of type `T`